# Haskell - interpreting a number

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I have a number 9877342931235. Using Haskell, I need to show it as:

987-734293-123-5

i've tried interspersing the list but of course that puts '-' between every digit. How would I do it to yield the actual result?

Comment: How would you do it in any other language?  Convert to string, regex the digit groups, concatenate with -?  Well, just do that in Haskell.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple general solution for splitting a list into parts of specified lengths and then joining them together with a specified delimiter:

```
splitercalate :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
splitercalate (x:[]) _     s = take x s
splitercalate (x:xs) delim s =
  case splitAt x s of
    (a, []) -> a
    (a, bs) -> a ++ delim ++ splitercalate xs delim bs
```

In your case `splitercalate [3, 6, 3, 1] "-" $ show 9877342931235` would give you what you want.

**UPDATE:** As [Antal S-Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237428/antal-s-z) notes in a comment below, you can implement this function more concisely by using functions from `Data.List` and `Data.List.Split`:

```
splitercalate chunks sep = intercalate sep . splitPlaces chunks
```

You would need to install the `split` package (probably by doing something like `cabal install split`), and import the `intercalate` and `splitPlaces` functions:

```
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Data.List.Split (splitPlaces)
```

The two versions should be equivalent. If you don't mind the extra `import`s and the dependency on the `split` package, use Antal S-Z's—it's much nicer.

Comment: Your `splitercalate` function is equivalent to `splitercalate chunks sep = intercalate sep . splitPlaces chunks`; `intercalate` is from `Data.List`, and `splitPlaces` is from [`Data.List.Split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.1.2).  Judging from the answers I've seen on StackOverflow, the split package is really underused—it's too bad, because the package is really nice.

Comment: wats this stuff from the data.list package though?

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you don't want to use Data.List.Split...

`import Data.List (intercalate)`

splitPlaces (n:ns) x = let (h, t) = splitAt n x
                       in h : splitPlaces ns t
splitPlaces _      x = []

splitercalate chunks sep = intercalate sep . splitPlace chunks

Your answer is then `concat . splitercalate [3,5,3,1] "-" $ show 9877342931235`